# Can't seem to get this assembly program to output at all

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64

I just started learning assembly ( < 1 week, so please forgive me if this is stupid), but I can't seem to figure out why this code won't produce an output:

```
section .data
    message db "Hello World!",10
    
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,message
    mov rdx,14
    syscall
    mov rax,60
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
```

I was following [this online tutorial](https://www.briansteffens.com/introduction-to-64-bit-assembly/01-hello-world/), along with a few others, but I can't seem to figure out why there isn't any output. It assembles and links without error (console input is: *nasm -f elf64 hello.asm -o hello.o*, followed by: *ld hello.o -o hello*. When ran, it takes a second, and then a new prompt appears).

I am on windows, which was all that I could find online for what the cause might be, but could not find a solution. I have tried using *-f win64* followed by *link.exe hello.obj /entry:_start /subsystem:console*
I have also swapped subsystem:console for subsystem:windows just in case, to no avail. I am completely lost, and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

P.S. If being on windows is the problem, is there a good guide online for nasm on windows. (I have tried masm and using as, but keep running into problems with them so I decided to opt for nasm)

Comment: Those are Linux system calls.  Windows is completely different.  You can't follow a Linux tutorial unless you use a VM or WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

Comment: What are the windows system calls, or do you know a good tutorial for windows I can follow. Either way, thank you for the help.

Comment: The actual `syscall` ABI on Windows is undocumented and only intended to be used by the Windows DLLs.  See [Make a program using only system-calls not windows dll's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44721985) for example.  What you're supposed to do is call WinAPI functions in the DLLs that the kernel maps into your process whether you want them or not.  As I said, look for a Windows NASM tutorial, e.g. [How to write hello world in assembler under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1023593) I think has an x64 answer

Answer (score 1):

A simple explanation: You can't use `syscall` on Windows. You need to import console writing functions from Windows DLLs and `call` them.

Comment: Hypothetically you *could* do direct system calls on Windows, but the [entry points](https://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/64/) keep changing around (even between different builds of the same major version number)

Comment: How do import the functions from dlls and then call them? I found a tutorial that uses global  _start
extern  puts
section .text
_start:
        sub     rsp, 28h
        mov     rcx, message
        call    puts
        add     rsp, 28h
        ret
message:
        db      'Hello', 0                                                                                                           as the code, but puts ends up being an unresolved external, I cannot find how to fix it. Is this the proper way to do it, is the code wrong, or am I still doing something wrong. Thank you!